# R using varibales in parLapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a problem with using the variable "Druckfaktor"  in `parLapply`.

My code looks like this:

```
  Druckfaktor <- 1.3      

  no_cores <- detectCores()-1
  cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

  S <- parLapply(cl,m.list,function(x) {
        s <- diag(x[2:4])
        s[1,2] <- s[2,1] <- x[5]
        s[2,3] <- s[3,2] <- x[6]
        s[3,1] <- s[1,3] <- x[7]

        VD <- eigen(s)
        V <- VD$vectors
        D <- VD$values
        D[D<0] <- D[D<0]/Druckfaktor
        s <- V %*% diag(D) %*% t(V)
        c(x[1],s[1,1],s[2,2],s[3,3],s[1,2],s[2,3],s[3,1])
  })
  stopCluster(cl)code here
```

Unfortunately the function answers with:

> `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
>     11 nodes produced errors; first error: Objekt 'Druckfaktor' nicht gefunden`

How can I use this "Druckfaktor" together with `parLapply`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `clusterExport`:

> `clusterExport(cl = NULL, varlist, envir = .GlobalEnv)`
>
> clusterExport assigns the values on the master R process of the variables named in varlist to variables of the same names in the global environment (aka ‘workspace’) of each node. The environment on the master from which variables are exported defaults to the global environment.

In your case:

```
Druckfaktor <- 1.3      

no_cores <- detectCores()-1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
clusterExport(cl, c("Druckfaktor"))
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesnt work.

Error in get(name, envir = envir) : invalid first argument

Comment: @Michael, even after fixing the typo `Druckfactor` -> `Druckfaktor`?  If so we will need a [mcve]?

Comment: ... solved, I have to hand over the name, i.e. "Druckfaktor" in quotation marks

Thanks for your help

Comment: @Michael, ok fixed in the answer as well. Fell free to accept/up-vote the answer.